# How do I create individual pages for a dataset

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I want to create individual pages for each headline gotten,but I have no clue how. i am also having problems with how the headline will be displayed on the homepage. i do not understand models at all, i thought i could just import the code to display on the homepage but from what i have been reading , i am miles away from seeing that happen ,lest creating individual pages for it. i have gone through listview and detailview i still do not understand. i started learning django only a week ago.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import timedelta, timezone, datetime
import os
import shutil



def scrape(response_text):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
        headlinees = soup.find_all(attrs={"itemprop": "headline"})
        for headline in headlinees:
            print(headline.text)


url = 'https://inshorts.com/en/read'
response = requests.get(url)
z = scrape(response.text)


# Create your views here.
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
#create model --headline(title,image,url)
#model -- userprofile(user,last_scrape)

class Headline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField()
    url = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Last_scrape = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return"{}-{}".format(self.user, self.last_scrape)
```

Comment: First, this is a pretty broad question. Second, that code is horribly structured and I wouldn't follow it.  Requests specifically has a method to pass things like API keys via dictionary structure and hard coding it into a URI isn't the best practice.  Read more: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Are you familiar with Django? You could save the headlines in a model and then use the views to display the pages.

Comment: @Chris okay, I'm new to Django. Thanks I'll do it.

Comment: Ok, goodd luck and come back if you need more help

Comment: i need more help